# AjaxFileUpload Iterate uploaded files afer files are uploaded

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I am using AjaxFileUpload control in Ajaxcontrol Toolkit.

Sample code is as below.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
AllowedFileTypes="doc,jpg,jpeg,mp3" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" runat="server"
OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
Width="450px" />

<asp:Button ID="btnCheckFiles" Text="CheckFiles" runat="server"/>
```

I can save the files in AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete event

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
   AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filepath);
}
```

Above is working fine but instead of saving files in UploadComplete event, I want to save them in Button Click event of another button after files are uploaded, here say in click event of btnCheckFiles, something like below

```
protected void btnCheckFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Iterate all files here uploaded 
  // for each file in ajaxfileupload control
  //iterate and save each file to a path
}
```

Is there some way to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Are you there Have you got solution?

Comment: No not yet. Not received any possible solutions to try for.

Comment: I have one solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide the solution?

Comment: See I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in your aspx page as follow:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnFileIDs" runat="server" Value="" />

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ThrobberID="myThrobber" 
AllowedFileTypes="doc,jpg,jpeg,mp3" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" runat="server"
OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
OnClientUploadComplete="onClientUploadComplete"
Width="450px" />
```

Add javascript block as follow:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
function onClientUploadComplete(sender, e) {
                var id = e.get_fileId();
                var objHdnFileIDs = document.getElementById('<%=hdnFileIDs.ClientID%>');
                objHdnFileIDs.value = objHdnFileIDs.value + id + ',';
               }
</script>
```

In your .cs page

```
  protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs file)
    {
         Session["fileContents_" + file.FileId] = file.GetContents();
         Session["fileExtension_" + file.FileId] = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
       //AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filepath);
    }

protected void btnCheckFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Iterate all files here uploaded 
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnFileIDs.Value))
        {
            string strFileIDs = hdnFileIDs.Value;
            string[] arrFileIDs = strFileIDs.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (arrFileIDs != null && arrFileIDs.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string strFileID in arrFileIDs)
                {
                    var fileContents = (byte[])Session["fileContents_" + strFileID];
                    var fileExtension = (string)Session["fileExtension_" + strFileID];

                    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath + strFileID + fileExtension, fileContents);
                    Session.Remove("fileContents_" + strFileID);
                    Session.Remove("fileExtension_" + strFileID);
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but you did not mention how to save file-contents in Session. Also will be advisable to save contents stream in Session? File can be of size in MBs even > 10 MB. Is not there a way we can fetch it from the AjaxFileUpload1 control itslef in btnCheckFiles_Click event?

Comment: Yes it is advisable to store the file content in session as you are not sorting it for long time after saving you are destroying that session in button click event. :)

Comment: have you implemented this answer?

Comment: No I haven't implemented the solution. Suggestion is fine but I am not implementing this uploader any more. I opted for another file uploader. Thanks once again

Comment: Thanks, this solution is worked for me, but I used file.get_fileName() in js code, to store file names in Hidden field, so I can save them later on specific button click.